# How to order by case insensitive ASC or DESC, with DISTINCT and UNION

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g

How to order by case insensitive ASC or DESC for P/L sql 11g. this p/l sql basic question but i can't find good answer in Google please tell how to sort the select result case insensitive

this what i tried

```
   SELECT  DISTINCT
            asssss,
            saas_acc
      FROM DUAL
   UNION SELECT '--ALL--','ALL' FROM DUAL
   ORDER BY  upper(asssss) ASC ;
```

that gave to me `ORA-01785: ORDER BY item must be the number of a SELECT-list expression`

Comment: Your query doesn't seem to make a lot of sense.  A `UNION` already does a `DISTINCT` so there is no reason for both.  Your top query is selecting two columns that do not exist in `dual`.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest option would be to sort by the upper- (or lower-) case column data

```
ORDER BY UPPER( column_name )
```

Comment: i tried this but that gave to me error as ORA-01785: ORDER BY item must be the number of a SELECT-list expression

Comment: @Duleep Please see Update1 of my answer.

Answer (score 1):

`DISTINCT` actually filtered the UNIQUE content in the result set, with whatever expressions given in the SELECT clause.

We cannot order it using a Different expression or column name. Please see the example here.

```
SQL> l
  1  SELECT DISTINCT  (col1),(col2)
  2  FROM
  3    ( SELECT 'Hello' col1,'World' col2 FROM DUAL
  4    UNION ALL
  5    SELECT 'HELLO','WORLD' FROM DUAL
  6*   )
SQL> /

COL1  COL2
----- -----
HELLO WORLD
Hello World
```

You can see that `DISTINCT` is `CASE SENSITIVE` here.(2 rows displayed)

---

So, let me Do a `UPPER()` on both columns.

```
SQL> l
  1  SELECT DISTINCT UPPER (col1),UPPER(col2)
  2  FROM
  3    ( SELECT 'Hello' col1,'World' col2 FROM DUAL
  4    UNION ALL
  5    SELECT 'HELLO','WORLD' FROM DUAL
  6*   )
SQL> /

UPPER UPPER
----- -----
HELLO WORLD
```

Just 1 row is Displayed, ignoring the case.

---

Coming back to the actual problem. To order something on a `DISTINCT` Resultset, it has to be a part of `DISTINCT` clause's expression/column.

So, When you issue `DISTINCT COL1,COl2`, the order by may be by `COL1` or `COL2`/.. it cannot be `COL3` or even `UPPER(COL1)` because UPPER() makes a different expression conflicting the expression over DISTINCT.

---

Finally, **Answer** for your *Question* would be

if you want your `ORDER` to be *case-insensitive*, `DISTINCT` also has to the same way! As given below

```
SELECT  DISTINCT
            UPPER(asssss),
            saas_acc
      FROM DUAL
   ORDER BY  upper(asssss) ASC ;
```

OR if UNION has to be used, better do this, or same as above one.

```
SELECT * FROM    
(
  SELECT  DISTINCT asssss as asssss,
          saas_acc
  FROM DUAL
 UNION
 SELECT '--ALL--','ALL' FROM DUAL
)
ORDER BY  upper(asssss) ASC ;
```

---

Out of my own *Experience*, I had always felt, what ever expression/column is specified in the `ORDER BY`, it is *implicitly* taken to final `SELECT` as well. Ordering is just based on the column number(position) in the result actually . In this situation, `DISTINCT COL1,COl2` is already there. When you give `ORDER BY UPPER(COL1)`, it will be tried to append into the `SELECT` expression, which is `NOT` possible at all. So, *Semantic* check itself, would *disqualify* this query with an **Error**!

Answer (score 0):

To sort case insensitive you need to set the NLS_COMP to ANSI

```
   NLS_COMP=ANSI
```

Details: http://www.orafaq.com/node/999

Answer (score 0):

You can use `upper` or `lower` functions.

```
order by upper(columnName)
```

**Update1**

Try removing `order-by` clause from your query which will give you correct error, which is `ORA-00904: "SAAS_ACC": invalid identifier`. So you can search on `google` for this error or ask another question on SO.

Also have a look at [how to use order by in union](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6036814/1551233).