# Ordering results with a union from the same table

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to show a group of results first in a list and then show the rest of the results from the table below.

I've tried [SQL: how to use UNION and order by a specific select?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6036793/sql-how-to-use-union-and-order-by-a-specific-select) but it doesn't appear to work in my case.

My query looks like this

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT id, display as ordered
      FROM table
     WHERE id in (...) --these need to be first
    UNION
    SELECT id, display
      FROM table
     WHERE id not in (...) --these need to be at the end
)
ORDER BY ordered
```

My results are coming back all ordered by display regardless of what I do.

I'm using Oracle, btw.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to include numbers to explicitly to get the ordering. This query orders the first result set first and then the second. In each group the results are again ordered by id. (remove it if not required)

```
SELECT id,display FROM (
    SELECT id, display,1 as ordered
      FROM table
     WHERE id in (...) --these need to be first
    UNION
    SELECT id, display,2 
      FROM table
     WHERE id not in (...) --these need to be at the end
)
ORDER BY ordered,id
```

Comment: @RobM Would you consider accepting the answer then? More users will be benefited this way.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should do this as:

```
select id, display
from table
order by (case when id in (. . .) then 1  -- first list
               when id in (. . .) then 3  -- last list
               else 2                     -- everything else
          end);
```

There is no need for `union` or `union all`.  Just a single `order by` expression.

You should include a `where` clause if you don't want all the ids.

(I find your question a bit unclear about what constitutes the lists.  You can use `not in` if that really is appropriate.)

Comment: ...and, perhaps, if needed, add id (or whatever else) as secondary ordering criteria